# Updating CSS Module @Value with React

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am using CSS module along with react. I want to change the border-radius dynamically from react. In the box.css , i set the border-radius as radiusValue. My goal is to modify the value of radiusValue from a react component. Is that possible? I couldn't find any solution related to updating the @value variable.

Thank you

inside box.css:

```
@value radiusValue:0px

.box{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 10px solid #595252;
    border-radius: radiusValue;
    padding: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that with CSS pre-processors, because they generate static files that can not be changed on the fly, 
but you can do this with pure CSS - specifically with [CSS Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).

**CSS file:**

```
:root {
  --radius-value: 0px;
}

.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 10px solid #595252;
    border-radius: var(--radius-value);
    padding: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

**JS file**

```
element.addEventListener("click", () => {
  root.style.setProperty("--radius-value", "20px")
})
```